# How to use "WWCalendarTimeSelector" third party in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4

[image]I am trying to integrate "WWCalendarTimeSelector" third party calendar in my project.i added this pod file using terminal.when i am importing this ,i am getting an error like

```
Could not build Objective-C module 'WWCalendarTimeSelector'
```

Can any one help me to do this, also let me know how to use this library in swift4 .Thank you.

```
import UIKit
import WWCalendarTimeSelector

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let selector = WWCalendarTimeSelector.instantiate()
        selector.delegate = self
        /*
         Any other options are to be set before presenting selector!
         */
        presentViewController(selector, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Specific Changes in **WWCalendarTimeSelector.swift** File.

replace with **`NSFontAttributeName`**  to **`NSAttributedStringKey.font`**

replace with **`NSForegroundColorAttributeName`**  to **`NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor`**

replace with **`NSParagraphStyleAttributeName`**  to **`NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle`**

then build again work fine for me in swift 4

Comment: I tried but at notifications and multipledate selector,i am getting an error

Comment: can you please add snapshot?

Comment: added the screenshot

Comment: as per you screenshot in the syntax error so please change line NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange like this

Comment: Put here project dropbox link so i will help you